# How to disable android hardware buttons in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building uber type application For that I want to disable all hardware buttons (home button, power button, application drawer button, back button) programmatically for specific screen

Comment: Are you building a new app in Ionic 3? Are you using Cordova? Ionic provides a handler for the Back button on Android (v3 docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/) but I think you will need a plugin for home, app drawer, etc. I've never done it.

Comment: Home button could not be disabled, for menu you could use ngIf on menu drawer like *ngIf="specificservice.active === true" and from other pages, that you want to  disable menu on, all you need is to set specicservice.active = false on enter the page you want to disable on, and on leave set the active to false to make the menu available again, and for back button, this.platform.backbutton.unsubscribe(); but for home button tou can't handle it..

Comment: thanks for replying, actually I can't find any plugin to handle home, app drawer, etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change home button functionality.

To change the back button event functionality use this code in your controller:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        //your code
    }, 100);
}
```

Good Luck!